# If an element is not present in an array how to find lower bound of the element using binary search

Tags: algorithm, search, binary

If an element is not present in an array how to find lower bound of the element using binary search

input: array size, element

5 4

array elements:

1 2 3 7 8

output: 2 [which is the index of lower bound]

```
     while(low <= high){
    int mid = (high + low)/2;

    if(a[mid] < s){
        low = mid + 1;
    }  
    else if(a[mid] >= s){
        high = mid - 1;
    }
}
```

[testcases 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIYIF.png)
[testcases 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDLNf.png)

Comment: What is the relationship between the element and the array?  As it stands no number can be an answer because someone else can always name a smaller number not in the array.

Comment: Lower Bound: The index of the largest value in the sorted array which is smaller or equal to S.
For repeating such values consider the smallest or the left-most index. If S is smaller than the
smallest value in the array, consider the lower bound as 0

Comment: Is the array assumed to be sorted?

Comment: yes, array is sorted

Comment: Do a binary search to find the last index of the lower bound.  Do another binary search to find its first index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't provide code for what I believe to be homework.  But I will offer advice because you have to be careful to get the edge cases on binary search right.  It took many years for anyone to produce a correct implementation, most textbook solutions were wrong for a shocking amount of time, and most professional programmers struggle with this one.

I have found it very helpful to distinguish between three variations on binary searches.  They can be coded like this:

```
-- Version 1.
while (low < high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (some condition on mid) {
        low = mid;
    } else {
        high = mid-1;
    }
}

-- Version 2.
while (low < high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (some condition on mid) {
        low = mid+1;
    } else {
        high = mid;
    }
}

-- Version 3.
while (low <= high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (lower bound condition on mid) {
        low = mid+1;
    } else if (upper bound condition on mid) {
        high = mid-1;
    }
    else {
        break, return, or otherwise indicate we have an answer
    }
}
```

The first two versions wind up with `low == high == the only possible answer`.  Which one to use requires careful thought about what `condition` told you about `mid`.

The third version is for searching for a specific value in the array.  This is a specific but important case, however MOST of my binary searches don't look like that.

Now in your case you need 2 searches.  The first is to find the LAST index whose value is a lower bound.  And the second to find the index of the FIRST time that value appears.  I don't think I'm giving too much away to say that I wouldn't write those the same way.

Good luck, and hopefully this problem causes you to better understand binary search by the time you are done!